# ActiveObjects repository with partial update

Tags: java

ActiveObjects is a ORM similar to ActiveObject.
This is a repository for it to be reused within my application.

I would like advise on:

1. Naming of the `CreatePeriodConfiguration` and
   `UpdatePeriodConfiguration`, do you have better ideas? I don't like
   verbs in class/interface names.
2. Do you think
   `CreatePeriodConfiguration` and `UpdatePeriodConfiguration` should
   be the same object, if so why?
3. This repository is exposing `Entity` which gives others a way to save each entity. Do you think
   this is a bad thing? Should the `PeriodConfigurationEntity` be
   encapsulated?
4. Naming of the repository does not match the `PeriodConfigurationEntity` but still `PeriodConfigurationEntityRepository` would be to long. Any suggestions for improvements?
5. Should I be exposing a ActiveObject entity?

   ```
   @Component
   public class PeriodConfigurationRepositoryImpl implements 
       PeriodConfigurationRepository {

       private final ActiveObjects ao;

       @Autowired
       public PeriodConfigurationRepositoryImpl(ActiveObjects ao) {
           this.ao = ao;
       }

       @Override
       public PeriodConfigurationEntity create(CreatePeriodConfiguration periodConfiguration) {
           PeriodConfigurationEntity entity = ao.create(PeriodConfigurationEntity.class,
                   new DBParam(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.START_DAY.name(), periodConfiguration.getStartDay()),
                   new DBParam(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.START_MONTH.name(), periodConfiguration.getStartMonth()),
                   new DBParam(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.DEFAULT_PERIOD.name(), periodConfiguration.isDefault())
           );
           return entity;
       }

       @Override
       public PeriodConfigurationEntity update(UpdatePeriodConfiguration periodConfiguration) {
           PeriodConfigurationEntity entity = get(periodConfiguration.getId());
           entity.setStartDay(periodConfiguration.getStartDay());
           entity.setStartMonth(periodConfiguration.getStartMonth());
           entity.save();
           return entity;
       }

       @Override
       public void delete(int id) {
           PeriodConfigurationEntity periodConfigurationEntity = get(id);
           for (PeriodEntity periodEntity : periodConfigurationEntity.getPeriods()) {
               ao.delete(periodEntity);
           }
           ao.delete(periodConfigurationEntity);
       }

       @Override
       public Collection<PeriodConfigurationEntity> getAll() {
           return getEntitiesByQuery(
                   Query.select(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.valuesToString())
           );
       }

       @Override
       public PeriodConfigurationEntity get(int id) {
           PeriodConfigurationEntity entity = find(id);
           if(entity == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("PeriodConfiguration with id %s not found.", id));
           }
           return entity;
       }

       @Override
       public PeriodConfigurationEntity find(int id) {
           return ao.get(PeriodConfigurationEntity.class, id);
       }

       @Override
       public PeriodConfigurationEntity findDefault() {
           return findPeriodConfigurationByScope(true);
       }

       @Override
       public PeriodConfigurationEntity findSecond() {
           return findPeriodConfigurationByScope(false);
       }

       private PeriodConfigurationEntity findPeriodConfigurationByScope(boolean isDefault) {
           Collection<PeriodConfigurationEntity> periodConfigurationEntities = getEntitiesByQuery(
                   new QueryBuilder()
                           .add(new QueryBuilder.EqClause(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.DEFAULT_PERIOD.name(), isDefault))
                           .build(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.valuesToString())
           );
           if (periodConfigurationEntities.iterator().hasNext()) {
               return periodConfigurationEntities.iterator().next();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean doesExist(int id) {
           Query query = new QueryBuilder()
                   .add(new QueryBuilder.EqClause(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.ID.name(), id))
                   .build(PeriodConfigurationEntity.PERIOD_CONFIG.ID.name());
           return ao.count(PeriodConfigurationEntity.class, query) > 0;
       }

       private Collection<PeriodConfigurationEntity> getEntitiesByQuery(Query query) {
           final Collection<PeriodConfigurationEntity> entities = Lists.newArrayList();
           ao.stream(PeriodConfigurationEntity.class, query, new EntityStreamCallback<PeriodConfigurationEntity, Integer>() {
               @Override
               public void onRowRead(PeriodConfigurationEntity periodConfigurationEntity) {
                   entities.add(periodConfigurationEntity);
               }
           });
           return entities;
       }
   }

   public class CreatePeriodConfiguration {

       private final int startDay;
       private final int startMonth;
       private final boolean isDefault;

       public CreatePeriodConfiguration(int startDay, int startMonth, boolean isDefault) {
           this.startDay = startDay;
           this.startMonth = startMonth;
           this.isDefault = isDefault;
       }

       public int getStartDay() {
           return startDay;
       }

       public int getStartMonth() {
           return startMonth;
       }

       public boolean isDefault() {
           return isDefault;
       }
   }

   public class UpdatePeriodConfiguration {

       private final int id;
       private final int startDay;
       private final int startMonth;

       public UpdatePeriodConfiguration(int id, int startDay, int startMonth) {
           this.id = id;
           this.startDay = startDay;
           this.startMonth = startMonth;
       }

       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public int getStartDay() {
           return startDay;
       }

       public int getStartMonth() {
           return startMonth;
       }
   }

   @Table("PERIOD_CONFIG")
   public interface PeriodConfigurationEntity extends Entity {

       enum PERIOD_CONFIG {
           ID,
           START_DAY,
           START_MONTH,
           DEFAULT_PERIOD;

           public static String valuesToString() {
               return StringUtils.join(values(), ",");
           }
       }

       @NotNull
       int getStartDay();
       void setStartDay(int startDay);

       @NotNull
       int getStartMonth();
       void setStartMonth(int startMonth);

       @NotNull
       @Default("false")
       boolean isDefaultPeriod();
       void setDefaultPeriod(boolean defaultPeriod);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is generally recommended to use nouns for class names because usually a class holds multiple methods each describing some action (create, update, etc.). Your class names (CreatePeriodConfiguration and UpdatePeriodConfiguration) look more like method names because they describe a specific action. Furthermore, I do not see any functional differences between CreatePeriodConfiguration and UpdatePeriodConfiguration. So, I would be using only one class, not two.

As I understand, you use these two classes to encapsulate parameters passed to create and update a PeriodConfigurationEntity. For that reason, I would try to name such class a PeriodConfigurationParamatesrWrapper or shorter PeriodConfigParametersWrapper or PeriodConfigParametesrHolder.